# Git code I used deleted everything

Tags: git

I tried a solution to a git problem I had:

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not
>   under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> ```
> -d = Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files
> -f = Force (might be not necessary depending on clean.requireForce setting)
> ```
>
> Run git help clean

Is it possible to get my changes back?

Comment: What was your current directory when you ran `git clean -df`?

Comment: i am not sure i use mac. the folder i cloned was stored directly on the highest level where all other files are stored.

Comment: Did you commit anything before running this?

Comment: i was trying to commit changes but i never let me.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, look at what Time Machine still has. Do it soon, before it trims backups.

Comment: I don't see a question here. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Updated with an actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Your changes are lost forever. `git clean -d` wipes out the changes totally (for untracked files).

The only thing you can do is scrolling up in the terminal, hoping to see one of the recent `git diff`'s.
Another option would be restoring deleted untracked files.

Next time, before doing any dangerous operations, I would recommend you to create an isolated patch file so you could easily reapply it in case of trouble.

Comment: git diff's? What do you mean?

Comment: Big mistake on my part... i was trying to push a Facebook app on heroku.

Comment: big mistake on my part. I was trying to push an application that i modified to heroku's server. It wasn't working and i was trying to many things without enough knowledge of git.

Comment: Can anyone guid me on a complete tutorial or documentation i can read?

Comment: `git diff` show you what changes you’ve made in your working directory (that have not been staged yet).

Comment: *github* has one of the best tutorial out there: http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: Stash won't protect you from `git clean` because by definition they operate on mututally exclusive sets by default.

Comment: diff --git a/Readme.md b/Readme.md
deleted file mode 100644
index 0550713..0000000
--- a/Readme.md
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,39 +0,0 @@
-Facebook/Heroku sample app -- PHP
-=================================
-
-This is a sample app showing use of the Facebook Graph API, written in PHP, des
-
-Run locally
------------
-
-Configure Apache with a `VirtualH
-
-Copy the App ID and Secret from the Facebook app settings page into your `Virtu
-
-    <VirtualHost *:80>
-        DocumentRoot /Users/adam/Sites/myapp
-        ServerName myapp.localhost